# VS2015 NuGet install error with SSL/TLS

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015

Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Unity.3.5.1404' with respect to project 'Web', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Unity.3.5.1404' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Unity.3.5.1404'
Resolved actions to install package 'Unity.3.5.1404'
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Attempting to gather dependencies information for package 'Unity.Mvc.3.5.1404' with respect to project Web', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Unity.Mvc.3.5.1404' from source 'nuget.org'.

Answer (score 1):

Finally that is company's Lan Net ban the connect.